# How to end while loop by pressing the 'Enter' key, not any alphabet key?

Tags: c

I want to end while loop by pressing the 'Enter' key, not any alphabet key. I could not figure out how I can do that.
I have done it such that, if the input is not the digit it will exit, but I want the input to be 'Enter' key.

```
void main (void)
            {
                float f;
                float total=0.0;
                printf("Enter numbers to be add: ");
                while (scanf("%f",&f)==1)
                    {
                        total=total+f;
                        printf("Enter another # to be add: ");
                                        scanf("%1.0f",&f);
                    }
                printf("Addition Total = %1.0f",total);
            }
```

Comment: what exact compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try `fgets`... should work.
http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/stdio.h/fgets.php

Answer (score 1):

using your frame work you should read in a string and then check if it is blank. If the string is blank you can end execution. If the string is not blank you should scanf the string.

Use sscanf (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) to read the string after you have verified that it is not blank.

Comment: I am sorry, my question is very basic programming related, that I want to end while loop by pressing the 'Enter' key, not any alphabet key. as i did inwhile (scanf("%f",&f)==1)

Comment: It is difficult to just "end" a program. In this case, a blank input such as "pressing the enter key" will leave only a new line white character "\n" or "\r\n" (maybe Windows). When your program encounters this special combination you will end your loop and the program will run to completion. Unlike scanf, we first check the input string and only if its good (not a stop command) to we convert that letter representation into a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fgets` and `sscanf` instead:

```
char buffer[100];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin))
{
    /* On DOS/Windows an empty line might be 2 characters ("\r\n") */
    if (strlen(buffer) == 1)
        break;    /* Only newline in buffer */

    if (sscanf(buffer, "%f", &f) == 1)
    {
        total += f;
        printf("Enter another number: ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use getch

```
 c = null
 while(c != 0x0D)
 {
    c = getch();
 }
```

[More info](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/getch)